# Help with finite dimensional cokernel implies closed range

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

I have an Operator $T \in L(X,Y)$ with finite dimensional cokernel.
I want to prove that $R(T)$ is closed.

So I extend $X':= X \times \mathbb R^n$ and $[y_i] := y_i + R(T)$ with $y_i\in Y$ so I get a basis of the cokernel.
$X'$ is clearly a Banach space and $T': X \times \mathbb R^n \to Y$ is surjective and so open.
$T'(x,\lambda) := Tx + \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_iy_i$.
So $T'(x,0) = T$.

Is there a way to conclude that $A:X \to R(T)$ or $A: X' \to R(T)$ with $R(T)$ normed space is open?
If so I can conclude than R(T) is a Banach space.

Comment: Your title mentions "cokernel" but the body of the text doesn't.  What exactly does "finite codimension" mean?  Once you exactly clarify this, you should see a different way to get the conclusion.  This is best asked on math.stackexchange as it is not research level mathematics.

Comment: I changed it. I know there are other ways to prove this but all ways i see are much longer than this. So i want this to give it a try. Should i then delete this question here?

Answer (score 1):

In Chapter IV, Theorem 5.10 of [A.E. Taylor and D.C.Lay. Introduction to functional analysis, 2nd edition, Wiley 1980] it is proved that if $T$ is a closed operator between Banach spaces $X$ and $Y$ (in particular if $T:X\to Y$ is a bounded operator), and there exists a closed subspace $M$ of $Y$ such that $R(T)\cap M=\{0\}$ and $R(T)+M$ is closed in $Y$ then $R(T)$ is closed.

In your case there exists a finite dimensional subspace $M$ such that $Y=R(T)\oplus M$.